# MySQL is creating new threads while connection is open

Tags: mysql

I have new MySQL 5.6 installation on Ubuntu 14.04
The problem is that from time to time, while connection to the database is still open, new thread is attached to the connection.
I have an open session and perform select connection_id();
After about 5 min, I am getting new ID.
In the SHOW PROCESSLIST I still see the old connection ID and the new one.
All temporary tables and variables are lost...
I have the same database running on Amazon RDS and have no such issue, when doing the same tests. I have compared all variables and found no significant differences

Comment: What client exactly are you using?

Comment: SQLYog for testing and Java for real